# Make $.getScript("") not add numbers at the end of the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

I am using `$.getScript()` to get a script from somewhere.

```
function fetch(url){
window.setInterval(function (){
$.getScript(url);
},50000)
}

fetch("http://example.com/script.js");
```

However, when I look at the FireBug developer console, I have seen that it adds additional ?numbers. Here is the output:

```
<script async="" src="http://example.com/script.js?7330519448833367000&_=1416681336440">
```

The remote server has disabled the ? char from their htaccess. I need to use `$.getScript("")` to get the remote script, but how is it possible to prevent the function that adding additional ?numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because jQuery sets caching to `false` (by default) when you use `$.getScript()`.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

> By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested.

To disable caching, add the following before the `$.getScript` call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

Comment: Where should I include it, inside the function or anywhere else ?

Comment: Before the line with ``$.getScript``

Answer (score 2):

`$.getScript()` tries to bypass the cache to always download the latest files. The numbers are a timestamp.

To disable this you need to set this propery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```