# Different cache method other than question mark?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `$.getscript("")` to get script from remote server.

```
function fetch(url){
window.setInterval(function (){
$.getScript(url);
},50000)
}

fetch("http://example.com/script.js");
```

It has non-cache by default, which we can see the output seems as

```
<script async="" src="http://example.com/script.js?7330519448833367000&_=1416681336440">
```

We can see that It always add the ?73325614 numbers, to not use the cached one always. But there is a problem, the remote server's htaccess prevents the "?" question mark in the URL. So that, I need to use another way to run my function than the question mark (non-caching) method. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Is the remote server smart enough to send headers instructing the browser not to cache?  If so, you don't need to use that hack anyway.

Comment: Nope. They just have added htaccess rule which prevents question marks in their urls.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe a hash (`#`) would work?

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question? [Make $.getScript("") not add numbers at the end of the request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081052/make-getscript-not-add-numbers-at-the-end-of-the-request)

Comment: Not really. Only the function is the same. But I am looking for a solution for another method.

Comment: I explained. In a nutshell, its "How to cache without using '?' mark" My previous question was how to cache in get.script.

Comment: What does the htaccess actually do?

Comment: It just prevents "?" question mark in the urls. Means, I cannot fetch the remote script, using "?" in the url. And getscript() adds the question marks automatically

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqxhr, settings) {
      // if `settings.url` string contains `?` character,
      // `.split()` `settings.url` string at `?` , creating `url` array
      // set `settings.url` to item at index `0` within `url` array :
      // original `settings.url` string , preceding `?` character
      if (/\?/.test(settings.url)) {
        var url = settings.url.split("?");
        if (url.length >= 2) {
            settings.url = url[0];
        }
      }
    }
})

var s = null;
function fetch(url) {
    s = window.setInterval(function () {
        $.getScript(url)
    }, 50000)
}

fetch("http://example.com/script.js");
```

See [jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax1) at `beforeSend` , [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqxhr, settings) {
      if (/\?/.test(settings.url)) {
        var url = settings.url.split("?");
        if (url.length >= 2) {
            settings.url = url[0];
            jqxhr.temp = settings.url
        }
      }
    }
})

var s = null;
function fetch(url) {
    s = window.setInterval(function () {
        $.getScript(url)
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(textStatus, jqxhr.temp, window.gist);
    $("#result").append(jqxhr.temp + "\n")
})
    // substitued 5000 for 50000
    }, 5000)
}

fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/ca95080f6d3a7b32bb95/raw/120dec0dce825193b0551ad1fbda4b71029b336d/js.js");
```

```css
#result {
    width : 300px;
    font-size : 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the different approach. Could you please explain a bit that what does this do ?